# I'm using an jQuery image gallery to show the same product in various colour. And i want to change the animation on click?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm using an jQuery image gallery to show the same product in various colour. And i want to change the animation on click? At the minute each click results in an image sweeping in from the left. However it is too flash for my site and i want simply replace the transition for one where the images never leave the screen. Could anyone help?

Here is my jQuery:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
$("#red").click(function () {
    $("#img-red").show('');

$("#img-etchedglass, #img-blue, #img- green").hide();
});
$("#blue").click(function () {
    $("#img-blue").show('');
    $("#img-etchedglass, #img-red, #img-green").hide();
});
$("#green").click(function () {
    $("#img-green").toggle('');
    $("#img-etchedglass, #img-red, #img-blue").hide();
});
});
$("#etchedglass").click(function () {
    $("#img-etchedglass").show('');
    $("#img-blue, #img-red, #img-green").hide();
});
```

I'm a novice when it comes to jQuery so any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

you can try to set animation duration to 0. Just use hide(0) or show(0);

Comment: Thanks, i have tried both and it makes no difference. It even animates the option bar.